# Printing a Linked list by users input

Tags: c

I am a beginner and I am attending to create and print a linked list by users input. Creating part goes well, but every time I try to print the final list, I get the annoying "LIST IS EMPTY" message. There is probably a problem with  *stnode pointer. Could anybody help me please? Thanks for every answer!

Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node
  {
  int data;
  struct node *next;
  }*stnode;

//function creating the linked list
void createnodelist(int n)
  {
  int num, i;
  struct node *stnode = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node)), *fnnode, *temp;

  if (stnode==NULL) {
    printf("Memory cannot be located");
    return;
    }

  //creating head of the list
  else {
    printf("Number 1 = ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    stnode->data = num;
    stnode->next = NULL;
    if (stnode == NULL) {
  printf("Memory can not be located");
      }
    temp = stnode;
    }

  //Creating all others parts of linked list
  for (i=2; i<=n; i++)
    {
    fnnode = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    if (fnnode==NULL) {
      printf("Memory cannot be located\n");
      break;
      }
    printf("Number %d = ", i);
    scanf("%d", &num);
    fnnode->data = num;
    fnnode->next = NULL;
    temp->next = fnnode;
    temp = temp->next;
    }
  }

//function printing the output
void printnode()
  {
  struct node *n = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

  n = stnode;
  if (stnode == NULL) {
    printf("LIST IS EMPTY"); //HERE IS MY PROBLEM
    }
  while (n!=NULL) {
    printf("%d ", n->data);
    n = n->next;
    }
  }    

int main()
  {
  int n;
  printf("Enter number of elements: ");
  scanf("%d", &n);
  printf("\n");

  createnodelist(n);
  printf("\n");

  printnode();

  printf("\n\n");
  return 0;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In createnotelist(), you are hiding the global *stnode* with the local declaration of the *stnode*. Because of that, the global *stnode* is remaining undefined or null and is not being modified in createnodelist().

Answer (score 0):

Your `createnodelist` function does nothing (except leak memory).

It declares a local variable called `stnode`:

```
struct node *stnode = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node)), *fnnode, *temp;
```

But that local variable is destroyed when the function returns, so there's no way to access the list you've built.

In particular, this `stnode` is unrelated to the global variable of the same name.

Your `printnode` function does this:

```
struct node *n = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

n = stnode;
```

(Note that this is a memory leak: `n = stnode` overwrites the pointer returned from `malloc`, which has now become inaccessible and cannot be freed.)

This `stnode` is a global variable. It was never set, so it still contains its initial value of `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

In `createnodelist`, write

```
void createnodelist(int n)
  {
  int num, i;
  stnode = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  struct node *fnnode, *temp;
```

instead of

```
void createnodelist(int n) {
  int num, i;
  struct node *stnode = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node)), *fnnode, *temp;
```

Otherwise, you introduce a local variable, which hides the global `stnode` used in your `printnode` function later on.

BTW: `struct node *n = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));` in `printnode` is superflous, since you overwrite the value of `n` in the next statement; Writing `struct node *n = stnode` instead is sufficient.